# linear-gradient IE11 white space issue

Tags: css

I'm trying to build a css framework for myself for some status boxes on my site.

I have put up an example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ravcg28r/

```
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(    left,  #aeaeae, #aeaeae 2em, transparent 2em, transparent 100% );
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( left,  #aeaeae, #aeaeae 2em, transparent 2em, transparent 100% );
    background: -o-linear-gradient(      left,  #aeaeae, #aeaeae 2em, transparent 2em, transparent 100% );
    background: linear-gradient(     to right,  #aeaeae, #aeaeae 2em, transparent 2em, transparent 100% );
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#aeaeae', endColorstr='#aeaeae',GradientType=1 );
```

It works really well in chrome and ff, but in IE 11 my linear gradient doesn't quite fill my span and I get an annoying little white space appearing around the border, see image and note the white space in the green box above the icon.

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

[linear gradient issue in IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAS41.png)

Comment: This is more and more related to zoom so please check your browser zoom setting.

Comment: Zoom is set to 100% when it occurs. so it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are using two Class into one, which can be confused. IE11 can be a nightmare but I have fixed it, and it should be ok on Ie11.

as you can see it on the 
https://www.codeply.com/go/8gTRzBR8Qd

Your code is

```
<tr>
<td><span class="sb sb-check sb-red">Some information</span></td>
<td>&lt;span class=&quot;sb sb-check sb-red&quot;&gt;Some information&lt;/span&gt;</td>
</tr>
```

I  change it, There is two similar class with sb and sb-red, so it better to remove one of them. I have changed some of the CSS as well.

```
<tr>
<td><span class="sb-red sb-check">Some information</span></td>
<td>&lt;span class="sb sb-check sb-red"&gt;Some information&lt;/span&gt;</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I did notice that if we apply a border radius it makes the issue worse. but by tweaking the border down as the radius goes up it removes it. This is the best solution. Many thanks!

Comment: No problem at all, IE11 is prone and trainwreck :-) if this is work for you, don't forget to tick the answer.

Comment: Update: I found that just using the border-width with some positioning produced a better/simpler result:

https://jsfiddle.net/mnfoo59k/2/

Answer (score 1):

I unfortunately don't exactly know why but it happens on 135% zoom in IE 10 and it seems to be a problem with border, not in gradient bg itself.

I managed to fix it changing `border` of `.sb-green` to this:

```
.sb-green {
     border: 0.21em solid #75de75 !important;/*please mind the 0.21 */
}
```

In pixels it failed to work at 4, 7.

I **guess** its some problem with IE rounding the border size when its calculated by fractions of sizes like 0.2em of 12px * 135% zooom etc. It wouldn't happen with pixel sizes I think... but I understand why you try to use relative ones ;-)